# First layer Z-offset in G-code

Tags: creality-ender-3, g-code, bltouch, z-probe

In slicer G-code is it possible to set the probe Z offset for the first layer only?

For my stock E3 plate I find -4.125 mm best however for glass I need to go to -4.175 mm for the first layer to get better adhesion. So it's a manual process every time. Any way to tell the slicer do the first layer at -4.175 mm and next ones at -4.125 mm?

Comment: Are you running stock firmware/Marlin firmware?

Comment: TH3D firmware, latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the reasoning behind a first layer having a different offset from the following layers, but, You can manually add a re-definition of the current height after the first layer, suppose your first layer is 0.2 mm, you just need to tell the printer to move to a slightly higher next layer to redefine this as a different Z-offset.

- From a G-code file find the start of the second layer:
  `G0 F600 X141.541 Y109.467 Z0.37`
- Modify this to:
  `G0 F600 X141.541 Y109.467 Z0.42`
- Now insert the following command:
  `G92 X0.37`

Now it is like you have changed the Z-offset.

The reason for not using `M206` is that is applied onto current offsets, if you accidentally save setting to memory after printing, it stores this offset. You can use `M206`, but use it carefully. A re-definition of the Z level is never stored, the next `G28` erases the effect, so does repowering the motors.

Comment: Hm I cannot find `G0` in PrusaSlicer printer settings G-code. Mine goes `M420` than `G1 Z2 F240..` Also is this just changing the layer heigh or actual Z offset ? I just found out about `M206` documentation says it can set the Z offset for the first layer but what is used after the setting on the printer or ?

Comment: @SterlingDuchess `G1` is identical to `G0` for e.g. Marlin and RepRap firmware. I wouldn't recommend using `M206`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to change the Z level (NOT the offset) during a print isn't a good idea UNLESS you know that all future moves will be "relative".

The `M206` (if you use Marlin) is the right way to set it!  Depending on the slicer, just create TWO "different" printer definitions and add them to the startup G-codes.

If you don't save it, a reset will return the z-offset to the "saved" value. Or consider resetting to a "standard" value in the ending G-code.

Also, consider using "baby-stepping" (if you can), and manually adjusting things at the start of a print with a different surface.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.